# How to restore a JSON string from a compressed blob in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to store a large json into a cell of a spreadsheet. Since there's a 50k character limit I thought of compressing the json string. I've managed to store the compressed blob as a base64 encoded string, but I'm failing to restore it to the original json. When the readLargeJson function is called I get the following error: "Blob object must have non-null content type for this operation".

The insertLargeJson function below seems to be working correctly.

I tried also storing without the base64 encoding, but didn't help.

```
function insertLargeJson()
{
    var obj = {};
    obj["dummy"] = [];

    // Just to make the json huge
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        obj["dummy"].push("value");
    }

    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(str, 'application/octet-stream');
    var compressedBlob = Utilities.zip([blob]);

    var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(compressedBlob.getDataAsString());

    activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(encoded);

}

function readLargeJson()
{
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var values = activeSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 1, 1);

    var value = values[0, 0];

    var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(value);

    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded);

    var unzipped = Utilities.unzip(blob);

    var obj = JSON.parse(unzipped.getDataAsString());

    Browser.msgBox('Test Json array size', "" + obj["dummy"].length, Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

I don't necessarily need to use the blob interface to compress the json, any solution that would compress the json string and that would be storable in a cell for later retrieving the original json would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an interesting concept so I search a bit and get something working.

In your code you have to use `compressedBlob.getBytes()` to encode data and not compressedBlob.getDataAsString(). To create a blob in your read function you must use bytes in input.

Then in your read function the unzip return an array and before to get the data you have to use the `getAs()` function. So you must have `unzipped[0].getAs('application/octet-stream').getDataAsString()` and not unzipped.getDataAsString()

I made a single function to ease testing, so you just have to split it depending your need.

```
function insertReadLargeJson(){
  var obj = {};
  obj["dummy"] = [];
  
  // Just to make the json huge
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    obj["dummy"].push("value");
  }
  //    Logger.log(obj)
  
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
  
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(str, 'application/octet-stream');
  var compressedBlob = Utilities.zip([blob]);
  
  var encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(compressedBlob.getBytes());
  
  activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(encoded);
  
  var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(encoded);
  
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded,'application/zip');
  
  var unzipped = Utilities.unzip(blob);
  
  var obj = JSON.parse(unzipped[0].getAs('application/octet-stream').getDataAsString());
  //    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
  Logger.log(obj.dummy.length)
  //    Logger.log('Test Json array size', "" + obj["dummy"].length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the help of an [external library](https://github.com/rgcl/jsonpack).

I converted the code to be readable by Apps Script:

## JSONPACK.gs

```
var TOKEN_TRUE = -1;
var TOKEN_FALSE = -2;
var TOKEN_NULL = -3;
var TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING = -4;
var TOKEN_UNDEFINED = -5;

function pack(json, options) {
  
  // Canonizes the options
  options = options || {};
  
  // A shorthand for debugging
  var verbose = options.verbose || false;
  
  verbose && console.log('Normalize the JSON Object');
  
  // JSON as Javascript Object (Not string representation)
  json = typeof json === 'string' ? this.JSON.parse(json) : json;
  
  verbose && console.log('Creating a empty dictionary');
  
  // The dictionary
  var dictionary = {
    strings : [],
    integers : [],
    floats : []
  };
  
  verbose && console.log('Creating the AST');
  
  // The AST
  var ast = (function recursiveAstBuilder(item) {
    
    verbose && console.log('Calling recursiveAstBuilder with ' + this.JSON.stringify(item));
    
    // The type of the item
    var type = typeof item;
    
    // Case 7: The item is null
    if (item === null) {
      return {
        type : 'null',
        index : TOKEN_NULL
      };
    }
    
    //add undefined 
    if (typeof item === 'undefined') {
      return {
        type : 'undefined',
        index : TOKEN_UNDEFINED
      };
    }
    
    // Case 1: The item is Array Object
    if ( item instanceof Array) {
      
      // Create a new sub-AST of type Array (@)
      var ast = ['@'];
      
      // Add each items
      for (var i in item) {
        
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        
        ast.push(recursiveAstBuilder(item[i]));
      }
      
      // And return
      return ast;
      
    }
    
    // Case 2: The item is Object
    if (type === 'object') {
      
      // Create a new sub-AST of type Object ($)
      var ast = ['$'];
      
      // Add each items
      for (var key in item) {
        
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key))
          continue;
        
        ast.push(recursiveAstBuilder(key));
        ast.push(recursiveAstBuilder(item[key]));
      }
      
      // And return
      return ast;
      
    }
    
    // Case 3: The item empty string
    if (item === '') {
      return {
        type : 'empty',
        index : TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING
      };
    }
    
    // Case 4: The item is String
    if (type === 'string') {
      
      // The index of that word in the dictionary
      var index = indexOf.call(dictionary.strings, item);
      
      // If not, add to the dictionary and actualize the index
      if (index == -1) {
        dictionary.strings.push(encode(item));
        index = dictionary.strings.length - 1;
      }
      
      // Return the token
      return {
        type : 'strings',
        index : index
      };
    }
    
    // Case 5: The item is integer
    if (type === 'number' && item % 1 === 0) {
      
      // The index of that number in the dictionary
      var index = indexOf.call(dictionary.integers, item);
      
      // If not, add to the dictionary and actualize the index
      if (index == -1) {
        dictionary.integers.push(base10To36(item));
        index = dictionary.integers.length - 1;
      }
      
      // Return the token
      return {
        type : 'integers',
        index : index
      };
    }
    
    // Case 6: The item is float
    if (type === 'number') {
      // The index of that number in the dictionary
      var index = indexOf.call(dictionary.floats, item);
      
      // If not, add to the dictionary and actualize the index
      if (index == -1) {
        // Float not use base 36
        dictionary.floats.push(item);
        index = dictionary.floats.length - 1;
      }
      
      // Return the token
      return {
        type : 'floats',
        index : index
      };
    }
    
    // Case 7: The item is boolean
    if (type === 'boolean') {
      return {
        type : 'boolean',
        index : item ? TOKEN_TRUE : TOKEN_FALSE
      };
    }
    
    // Default
    throw new Error('Unexpected argument of type ' + typeof (item));
    
  })(json);
  
  // A set of shorthands proxies for the length of the dictionaries
  var stringLength = dictionary.strings.length;
  var integerLength = dictionary.integers.length;
  var floatLength = dictionary.floats.length;
  
  verbose && console.log('Parsing the dictionary');
  
  // Create a raw dictionary
  var packed = dictionary.strings.join('|');
  packed += '^' + dictionary.integers.join('|');
  packed += '^' + dictionary.floats.join('|');
  
  verbose && console.log('Parsing the structure');
  
  // And add the structure
  packed += '^' + (function recursiveParser(item) {
    
    verbose && console.log('Calling a recursiveParser with ' + this.JSON.stringify(item));
    
    // If the item is Array, then is a object of
    // type [object Object] or [object Array]
    if ( item instanceof Array) {
      
      // The packed resulting
      var packed = item.shift();
      
      for (var i in item) {
        
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(i)) 
          continue;
        
        packed += recursiveParser(item[i]) + '|';
      }
      
      return (packed[packed.length - 1] === '|' ? packed.slice(0, -1) : packed) + ']';
      
    }
    
    // A shorthand proxies
    var type = item.type, index = item.index;
    
    if (type === 'strings') {
      // Just return the base 36 of index
      return base10To36(index);
    }
    
    if (type === 'integers') {
      // Return a base 36 of index plus stringLength offset
      return base10To36(stringLength + index);
    }
    
    if (type === 'floats') {
      // Return a base 36 of index plus stringLength and integerLength offset
      return base10To36(stringLength + integerLength + index);
    }
    
    if (type === 'boolean') {
      return item.index;
    }
    
    if (type === 'null') {
      return TOKEN_NULL;
    }
    
    if (type === 'undefined') {
      return TOKEN_UNDEFINED;
    }
    
    if (type === 'empty') {
      return TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING;
    }
    
    throw new TypeError('The item is alien!');
    
  })(ast);
  
  verbose && console.log('Ending parser');
  
  // If debug, return a internal representation of dictionary and stuff
  if (options.debug)
    return {
      dictionary : dictionary,
      ast : ast,
      packed : packed
    };
  
  return packed;
  
};

function unpack(packed, options) {
  
  // Canonizes the options
  options = options || {};
  
  // A raw buffer
  var rawBuffers = packed.split('^');
  
  // Create a dictionary
  options.verbose && console.log('Building dictionary');
  var dictionary = [];
  
  // Add the strings values
  var buffer = rawBuffers[0];
  if (buffer !== '') {
    buffer = buffer.split('|');
    options.verbose && console.log('Parse the strings dictionary');
    for (var i=0, n=buffer.length; i<n; i++){
      dictionary.push((buffer[i]));
    }
  }
  
  // Add the integers values
  buffer = rawBuffers[1];
  if (buffer !== '') {
    buffer = buffer.split('|');
    options.verbose && console.log('Parse the integers dictionary');
    for (var i=0, n=buffer.length; i<n; i++){
      dictionary.push(base36To10(buffer[i]));
    }
  }
  
  // Add the floats values
  buffer = rawBuffers[2];
  if (buffer !== '') {
    buffer = buffer.split('|')
    options.verbose && console.log('Parse the floats dictionary');
    for (var i=0, n=buffer.length; i<n; i++){
      dictionary.push(parseFloat(buffer[i]));
    }
  }
  // Free memory
  buffer = null;
  
  options.verbose && console.log('Tokenizing the structure');
  
  // Tokenizer the structure
  var number36 = '';
  var tokens = [];
  var len=rawBuffers[3].length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var symbol = rawBuffers[3].charAt(i);
    if (symbol === '|' || symbol === '$' || symbol === '@' || symbol === ']') {
      if (number36) {
        tokens.push(base36To10(number36));
        number36 = '';
      }
      symbol !== '|' && tokens.push(symbol);
    } else {
      number36 += symbol;
    }
  }
  
  // A shorthand proxy for tokens.length
  var tokensLength = tokens.length;
  
  // The index of the next token to read
  var tokensIndex = 0;
  
  options.verbose && console.log('Starting recursive parser');
  
  return (function recursiveUnpackerParser() {
    
    // Maybe '$' (object) or '@' (array)
    var type = tokens[tokensIndex++];
    
    options.verbose && console.log('Reading collection type ' + (type === '$' ? 'object' : 'Array'));
    
    // Parse an array
    if (type === '@') {
      
      var node = [];
      
      for (; tokensIndex < tokensLength; tokensIndex++) {
        var value = tokens[tokensIndex];
        options.verbose && console.log('Read ' + value + ' symbol');
        if (value === ']')
          return node;
        if (value === '@' || value === '$') {
          node.push(recursiveUnpackerParser());
        } else {
          switch(value) {
            case TOKEN_TRUE:
              node.push(true);
              break;
            case TOKEN_FALSE:
              node.push(false);
              break;
            case TOKEN_NULL:
              node.push(null);
              break;
            case TOKEN_UNDEFINED:
              node.push(undefined);
              break;
            case TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING:
              node.push('');
              break;
            default:
              node.push(dictionary[value]);
          }
          
        }
      }
      
      options.verbose && console.log('Parsed ' + this.JSON.stringify(node));
      
      return node;
      
    }
    
    // Parse a object
    if (type === '$') {
      var node = {};
      
      for (; tokensIndex < tokensLength; tokensIndex++) {
        
        var key = tokens[tokensIndex];
        
        if (key === ']')
          return node;
        
        if (key === TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING)
          key = '';
        else
          key = dictionary[key];
        
        var value = tokens[++tokensIndex];
        
        if (value === '@' || value === '$') {
          node[key] = recursiveUnpackerParser();
        } else {
          switch(value) {
            case TOKEN_TRUE:
              node[key] = true;
              break;
            case TOKEN_FALSE:
              node[key] = false;
              break;
            case TOKEN_NULL:
              node[key] = null;
              break;
            case TOKEN_UNDEFINED:
              node[key] = undefined;
              break;
            case TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING:
              node[key] = '';
              break;
            default:
              node[key] = dictionary[value];
          }
          
        }
      }
      
      options.verbose && console.log('Parsed ' + this.JSON.stringify(node));
      
      return node;
    }
    
    throw new TypeError('Bad token ' + type + ' isn\'t a type');
    
  })();
  
}

function indexOfDictionary (dictionary, value) {
  
  // The type of the value
  var type = typeof value;
  
  // If is boolean, return a boolean token
  if (type === 'boolean')
    return value ? TOKEN_TRUE : TOKEN_FALSE;
  
  // If is null, return a... yes! the null token
  if (value === null)
    return TOKEN_NULL;
  
  //add undefined
  if (typeof value === 'undefined')
    return TOKEN_UNDEFINED;
  
  
  if (value === '') {
    return TOKEN_EMPTY_STRING;
  }
  
  if (type === 'string') {
    value = encode(value);
    var index = indexOf.call(dictionary.strings, value);
    if (index === -1) {
      dictionary.strings.push(value);
      index = dictionary.strings.length - 1;
    }
  }
  
  // If has an invalid JSON type (example a function)
  if (type !== 'string' && type !== 'number') {
    throw new Error('The type is not a JSON type');
  };
  
  if (type === 'string') {// string
    value = encode(value);
  } else if (value % 1 === 0) {// integer
    value = base10To36(value);
  } else {// float
    
  }
  
  // If is number, "serialize" the value
  value = type === 'number' ? base10To36(value) : encode(value);
  
  // Retrieve the index of that value in the dictionary
  var index = indexOf.call(dictionary[type], value);
  
  // If that value is not in the dictionary
  if (index === -1) {
    // Push the value
    dictionary[type].push(value);
    // And return their index
    index = dictionary[type].length - 1;
  }
  
  // If the type is a number, then add the '+'  prefix character
  // to differentiate that they is a number index. If not, then
  // just return a 36-based representation of the index
  return type === 'number' ? '+' + index : index;
  
};

function encode(str) {
  if ( typeof str !== 'string')
    return str;
  
  return str.replace(/[\+ \|\^\%]/g, function(a) {
    return ({
      ' ' : '+',
      '+' : '%2B',
      '|' : '%7C',
      '^' : '%5E',
      '%' : '%25'
    })[a]
  });
};

function decode(str) {
  if ( typeof str !== 'string')
    return str;
  
  return str.replace(/\+|%2B|%7C|%5E|%25/g, function(a) {
    return ({
      '+' : ' ',
      '%2B' : '+',
      '%7C' : '|',
      '%5E' : '^',
      '%25' : '%'
    })[a]
  })
};

function base10To36(number) {
  return Number.prototype.toString.call(number, 36).toUpperCase();
};

function base36To10(number) {
  return parseInt(number, 36);
};

function indexOf(obj, start) {
  for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (this[i] === obj) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```

With that, your script can now be:

## Code.gs

```
function insertLargeJson()
{
  var obj = {};
  obj["dummy"] = [];
  // Just to make the json huge
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    obj["dummy"].push("value");
  }

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var packed = pack(obj);
  
  var value = JSON.stringify(packed);
  
  activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(value);
}

function readLargeJson()
{
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var value = activeSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  
  var packed = JSON.parse(value);
  
  var obj = unpack(packed);
  
  Browser.msgBox('Test Json array size', "" + obj["dummy"].length, Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

Hope this helps!